# Excel formula to compare a cell with other cells in a selected range

Tags: excel, text, compare, average, countif

my name is Diego and i'm in need of your knowledge:

I have a selected range of cells in a column and i need to compare one cell value (text) with the other cells in the selected range. the idea is to get the % of difference that rows have to the rest of values among columns, for example:

```
  A   B   C
 Yes Yes  0%
 Yes Yes  0%
 Yes Yes  0%
 Yes Yes  0%
 N/A Yes  50%
 Yes Yes  0%
 Yes Yes  0%
 Yes No   50%
```

i have a formula that is capable of doing the job for one column. the aim of this formula is to state if the selected cell is diferent than the others, so if it is, and its part of the minority (lets say lower than 50% of the selected choices), to add 1. if it is the same value as the majority, dont add a value (or add 0). i know it seems tricky, so i'll explain with the formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$10;$A1)/COUNTA($A$1:$A$10)>0,5;0;1)
```

The formula is filled down, so the the formula keeps comparing among the range of formulas. 
But, as you can see on column C, the idea is to get an average of this individual comparisons. a formula:

```
=AVERAGE(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$10;$A1)/COUNTA($A$1:$A$10)>0,5;0;1);COUNTIF($B$1:$B$10;$B1)/COUNTA($B$1:$B$10)>0,5;0;1))
```

So i just take an average of the formula repeated for each column in the range of cells that are with data.

Here's where it get's real tricky...

the idea is to make the formula to tell if there's a TIE and in which column. so to say:

```
 A   B   C
Yes Yes TIE IN COLUMN A
Yes Yes TIE IN COLUMN A
N/A Yes TIE IN COLUMN A
Yes Yes TIE IN COLUMN A
N/A Yes TIE IN COLUMN A
N/A Yes TIE IN COLUMN A
Yes Yes TIE IN COLUMN A
N/A No  TIE IN COLUMN A
```

Please advise me in this matter!! your help is very welcome.
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I'm slightly confused - what determines if there's a tie in the columns? If the Count and the Average formulas are equal?

Comment: there's a tie if in a column half of the values are "x" and the other half is "y". so, if the value "x" is found 4 times in a column with 8 rows, and the value "y" is found the same 4 times, is a tie between "x" and "y" in that column. the idea is to make the formula if theres a tie, but if there's not, to calculate the formula that i posted first

Comment: I can't quite figure out what you are saying. In the example you give at the bottom of your question, half the entries are "Yes" and half are "N/A" so -- I guess that is what you mean by a tie. But -- you seem to want to copy some formula down column C which simply repeats this fact in such a way that the row isn't relevant. Why have multiple instances that repeat the same fact? Also what if *both* column A and column B have the property that they have ties? What if neither?

Comment: I would say your example is wrong. Since there is no base line ... why is the 50% the = 0% and all the rest 50% for that matter the 50% in your example are 100% different from eachother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think this will do what you want, keep in mind the ranges are probably not what you want

```
=IFERROR((IF(A2=INDEX($A$2:$A$11,MODE(MATCH($A$2:$A$11,$A$2:$A$11,0)+{0,0})),1,0)+IF(B2=INDEX($B$2:$B$11,MODE(MATCH($B$2:$B$11,$B$2:$B$11,0)+{0,0})),1,0))/2,"")
```

I am not sure exactly what you are talking about in your 2nd part, but maybe this gets you all you need.